# No logro mostrar los valores de mi base de datos en una grafica utilizando chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

estoy intentando practicar con chartjs, por eso he bajado un código de Internet para adaptarlo a mis necesidades.

Necesito mostrar la cantidad de pacientes que nacieron en un mes especifico según sus fechas de nacimientos al igual que su año de nacimiento.

El tema esta en que he buscado toda forma para mostrar la información que tengo en mi base de datos en la gráfica y no hallo la forma, ya que el código de las gráficas esta en un archivo javascript externo.

Llevo mucho tiempo intentando resolver esto, por favor, agradecería enormemente que alguien pudiera ayudarme

**Tabla pacientes**

```
CREATE TABLE `pacientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre_documento` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `num_documento` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `telf` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `embarazo` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `embarazo_arriesgado` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `semanas_gestacion` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tela_mosquitera` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pacientes`
--

INSERT INTO `pacientes` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `nombre_documento`, `num_documento`, `telf`, `sexo`, `embarazo`, `fecha_nacimiento`, `embarazo_arriesgado`, `semanas_gestacion`, `tela_mosquitera`) VALUES
(6, 'marta', 'mangue', 'dip', 655, 222987665, 'Femenino', '', '2021-12-28', '', '', ''),
(7, 'Mayo', 'Esono', 'dip', 5769, 551233234, 'Masculino', '', '2021-10-25', '', '', ''),
(40, 'Celso', 'NUESTRA', 'dip', 4334, 4343, 'Masculino', '', '2021-11-19', '', '', ''),
(41, 'Nathan', 'Narby Esimi', 'dip', 1111, 654890, 'Masculino', '', '2021-12-28', '', '', '');
```

**chart.js**

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctxGreen, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipGreen

    });
```

Aqui es donde me gustaria que apareciera mi infirmacion

```
    var chart_labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
    var chart_data = [100, 70, 90, 70, 85, 60, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100];


    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartBig1").getContext('2d');

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.1)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors
    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: chart_labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
          borderColor: '#d346b1',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [],
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          pointBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
          pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
          pointBorderWidth: 20,
          pointHoverRadius: 4,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
          pointRadius: 4,
          data: chart_data,
        }]
      },
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    };
    var myChartData = new Chart(ctx, config);
    $("#polio").click(function() {
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });
    $("#sarampion").click(function() {
      var chart_data = [80, 120, 105, 110, 95, 105, 90, 100, 80, 95, 70, 120];
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });

    $("#paludismo").click(function() {
      var chart_data = [60, 80, 65, 130, 80, 105, 90, 130, 70, 115, 60, 130];
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });


    var ctx = document.getElementById("CountryChart").getContext("2d");

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(29,140,248,0.2)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(29,140,248,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(29,140,248,0)'); //blue colors
```

**inicio.php** este es el archivo php en donde se muestra la grafica

```
<?php include("plantillas/header.php"); ?>

<!--CONTENIDO DE LA PAGINA -->
<section class="panelControl">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="plantillas/header.php"></a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 titulo-panel">
                <h2 class="card-title">Panel de administración</h2>
                <p>Consulte las estadisticas de los pacientes</p>

<div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card  custom-card">
                <div class="card-header ">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                        <h5 class="card-category">Total pacientes</h5>
                        <h2 class="card-title">Estadística de los pacientes registrados</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle float-right" data-toggle="buttons">
                           
                        
                        <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-simple active" id="polio">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" checked>
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">Polio</span>
                            <span class="d-block d-sm-none">
                            <i class="tim-icons icon-single-02"></i>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-simple" id="sarampion">
                            <input type="radio" class="d-none d-sm-none" name="options">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">Sarampion</span>
                            <span class="d-block d-sm-none">
                            <i class="tim-icons icon-gift-2"></i>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-simple" id="paludismo">
                            <input type="radio" class="d-none" name="options">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">Paludismo</span>
                            <span class="d-block d-sm-none">
                            <i class="tim-icons icon-tap-02"></i>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chart-area">
                    <canvas id="chartBig1"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema? En donde estas entrampado exactamente?

Comment: @Yussef mi problema esta en que al ser un archivo js externo, no sabria como introducir el codigo php en este archivo para hacer las consultas a la BD